# .htaccess for showing all data

Tags: php, .htaccess

How can I show all data using REST API according to `.htaccess` syntax ?

**`.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^read/([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ read.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^semua/?$ semua.php [NC,L]
```

When calling `read.php` to show some data from `index.php`, all specific phonebrand are show up:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$url = "http://localhost/api/simpel/items/read/phonebrand";
$client = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response = curl_exec($client);
```

But when calling `semua.php` from `index.php`, postman show nothing:

```
$url = "http://localhost/api/simpel/items/semua";
$client = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response = curl_exec($client);
```

What is the correct `.htaccess` to allow showing all data?

---

**`read.php`**:

```
<?php
include_once("../db_connect.php");

if(!empty($_GET['name'])) {

    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $items = getItems($name, $conn);

    if(empty($items)) {
        jsonResponse(200,"Items Not Found",NULL);
    } else  {
        jsonResponse(200,"Item Found",$items);
    }
} else {
    jsonResponse(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);
}

function jsonResponse($status,$status_message,$data) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status_message);
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}

function getItems($name, $conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.created FROM items p WHERE p.name LIKE '%".$name."%' ORDER BY p.created DESC";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $data;
}


?>
```

**`semua.php`**:

```
<?php
include_once("../db_connect.php");

$items = getItems($conn);

function jsonResponse($status,$status_message,$data) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
    header("Content-Type:application/json");
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status_message);
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}

function getItems($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items p ORDER BY p.created DESC";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: Does semua.php generate any output? I only see a definition of `jsonResponse` function, but no calls to it...

Comment: read.php output :
{"status":400,"status_message":"Invalid Request","data":null}

semua.php output nothing

Comment: update :
i add jsonResponse(400,"Invalid Request",NULL); on semua.php 

and show this :
 jsonResponse(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);

Answer (score 0):

found temporary answer after trying several hours.

change .htaccess to :

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^read/([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ read.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^semua/([a-zA-Z_-]*)$ semua.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

and semua.php to :

```
<?php
include_once("../db_connect.php");

if(!empty($_GET['name'])) {

    $name=$_GET['name'];
    $items = getItems($name, $conn);

    if(empty($items)) {
        jsonResponse(200,"Items Not Found",NULL);
    } else  {
        jsonResponse(200,"Item Found",$items);
    }
} else {
    jsonResponse(400,"Invalid Request",NULL);
}

function jsonResponse($status,$status_message,$data) {
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
header("Content-Type:application/json");
    header("HTTP/1.1 ".$status_message);
    $response['status']=$status;
    $response['status_message']=$status_message;
    $response['data']=$data;
    $json_response = json_encode($response);
    echo $json_response;
}

function getItems($name, $conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items p ORDER BY p.created DESC";
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    $data = array();
    while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        $data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $data;
}


?>
```

and call from index.php with :

```
$url = "http://localhost/api/simpel/semua/all";
$client = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$response = curl_exec($client);
```